# Induced Comonad of a Monad on the Eilenberg-Moore and the Kleisli category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

It is well known that for every monad T, we can consider the Eilenberg-Moore-Category and get an adjunction which induces T, similar for the Kleisli-Category. But since every adjunction induces a Comonad as well, my question is what are the Comonads in the Eilenberg-Moore-Category resp. the Kleisli-Category that are induced by T in this way?

Comment: There are some relevant references on the nLab page [nuclear adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nuclear+adjunction).